# Excel, creating a hyperlink that goes to a column without specifying a row

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have a sheet with 6 different tables (and then multiple sheets (20 copies) that are similar but under different names). The tables are long (columns B to Az).

I want to put a link in each table that will jump to column W. I am trying to avoid make 6 different cell references hyperlinks on each sheet. Is there a way to get this down besides the manual hyperlinking each one of those?

This sheet is going to be used on Excel Online, so cannot use any VBA. (If I have to run a VBA code to make it happen then remove the VBA that works, but end product wont support any VBA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean with "without specifying a row" - but jumping to a column without naming the sheet can be done with the HYPERLINK formula

Just insert into a cell

```
=HYPERLINK("#W1","Click here to jump to W1")
```

You can then paste this formula to all sheets

But i think you would need to name the range you want to jump to. It would also be possible to select the whole column

```
=HYPERLINK("#W:W","Click here to jump to W")
```

And of course, dynamic links are also possible and can be very useful - jump to the first empty row of a given sheet, for example.

Comment: Ah, yes well to clarify my original question more. Lets say the hyperlink is placed in  cells a1 ,  a50, a100, and a400, (about 6 links total) I wanted to hyperlink to just jump to Column AZ1, AZ50, AZ100, etc.

However, your solution works. I previously only ever used Hyperlink by rightclicking and doing it from the menu, which forced a sheetname reference and thus i couldn't just copy and paste it to the 20+ sheets.

The hyperlink formula works perfect thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Was my first time I considered that formula helpful, too ;)